# Wordpress URL Routing

Tags: wordpress, url-routing

I'm using an external api to populate an article page in wordpress.

Right now I'm having to use a url fragment to define the slug and load a specific article like this.

http://example.com/article#some-api-story-slug

I need the slug to be the last path component

http://example.com/article/some-api-story-slug

Is it possible to accomplish this without the use of Redirects

The ideal solution would be to intercept the last part of the route as a wildcard and pass it along to a page template, like you can do with most other framework, but I haven't had much luck finding a similar solution for Wordpress.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the rewrite API http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Comment: Thanks Dave, you're right, that does look promising. However I tried adding the function from the `Creating a “welcome” rewrite rule` section of https://carlalexander.ca/wordpress-adventurous-rewrite-api/ and it simply left me with a blank page (and a 500 error). And ideas on that.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Was simply a matter of the functions.php file I was using. Ended up having a separate issue because `/articles/%post_name%/` was the existing permalink used for items other than news, but that's something all together different. Thanks Dave for your help.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because know it worked this way helped me out.